# why isn't this polynomial addition not working?

Tags: c, linked-list

So this is the snippet where the addition happens after taking in the two polynomials. The last part of it where i try to display the sum is where in i get stuck. what i don't get is why shouldn't the while loop work. can anyone help?! 
PS:Functions is something that i couldn't use in here.. some other restrictions due to the question's requirements.
PPS:Also i know that you might think that it's a very basic program and believe me when i say that i know it is.. but i really need help brushing up on these basic skills and any help at all would be appreciated.

```
struct poly
{ int e;float c;
  struct poly *next;
};
typedef struct poly node;

r = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node)); //r is a node of structure
p3 = r;
if((p3 == NULL) || (r == NULL)) { printf("insuf mem");return;}

while ( (p1!=NULL) && (p2!=NULL) ) {
if( p1->e == p2->e) {
 r->e = p1->e;
 r->c = (p1->c) + (p2->c);
 p1 = p1->next;
 p2 = p2->next;
 r->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 r = r->next;
}
else if ( (p1->e) > (p2->e) ) {
 r->e = p1->e;
 r->c = p1->c;
 p1 = p1->next;
 r->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 r = r->next;
}
else {
 r->e = p2->e;
 r->c = p2->c;
 p2 = p2->next;
 r->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 r = r->next;
 }
/* if( (p1 == NULL)&&(p2==NULL) )
 r->next=NULL;
 else
 r = r->next;*/
}

while (p1!=NULL)
{
 r->e = p1->e;
 r->c = p1->c;
 p1 = p1->next;
 r->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 r = r->next;
 /*if(p1!=NULL)
  r = r->next;
 else r->next=NULL;*/
}

while (p2!=NULL)
{
 r->e = p2->e;
 r->c = p2->c;
 p2 = p2->next;
 r->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
 r = r->next;
/* if(p2!=NULL)
  r = r->next;
 else r->next=NULL;*/
}
r=NULL;


printf("\n\nThe sum is\n");
while(p3!=NULL) {
printf("%3.2f X^%d + ",p3->c,p3->e);
p3 = p3->next;
}

getch();
}
```

Comment: Infinite loop? What gdb said about that? BTW don't cast malloc() return value...

Comment: Try adding a printf("p3=%p\n", p3) to the start of your final loop.  It will print out the value of the pointer p3 at each iteration.  You'll probably see that there is a cycle in your linked list and that is why it never "ends".

Comment: Wall of code. Bleah. However, the `free(r)` calls after the `for` loops in `main()` look rather suspect.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: why shouldn't i cast malloc's return value. it';s after casting it only that the pointer will know what type of data will it be storing right?

Comment: @MichaelBurr:The free is for simply letting the pointer r start from a fresh allocated memory.

Comment: _"start from a fresh allocated memory"_, yes and **deleting previous allocated one**. In C (not C++) you don't need to cast void* to destination type, it's a bad practice simply because it's useless (conversion is implicit) and it may hide subtle errors (for example if you forget to include  malloc).

Comment: @AnkR: I think that it's freeing the last item you add to the list (I'm not sure because I haven't studied the code carefully enough - it just looks like something that should be carefully checked).  As for casting the result of `malloc()`, the cast is unnecessary in C and performing a cast can hide a problem if you don't have `stdlib.h` included.  However, C++ would require the cast (because of different rules in how `void*` is handled).  Many people on SO are rather militant about not casting the result of `malloc()` and not using it in C++ code.

Comment: Alright so i get the thing about malloc now. i will try to keep that in mind. every online tutorial i saw used the typecasting method and hence i did too. any way if there's still anything wrong with the addition code snippet, let me know please, so that i may figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
r->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
r = r->next;
```

ask yourself what the contents of `r` is:

```
r->e = ?;
r->c = ?;
r->next = ?;  // Important!
```

The answer is that the contents of `r` is unknown/undefined. Since this will be the last node in your linked list starting at `p3` and it is very unlikely that `r->next` will happen to be `NULL` you have no "end" to your list.

To fix this you need to initialize the contents of all new nodes like:

```
r->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
r = r->next;

r->next = NULL;  //Initialize new node at end of list
r->c = 0;
r->e = 0;
```